# Tensorflow: construct sparse matrix from its diagonals

Tags: python, tensorflow

Could you tell me, is there an analog of scipy.sparse.diags in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

Here are all the [tensorflow matrix operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops/matrix_math_functions). There are some diagonal construction facilities, but there is not a 1:1 scipy.sparse.diags function. What you can do is to generate the matrix in scipy and then pass it to tensorflow.